# View based on apex collection

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

in my application I have a view based on an apex collection:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "INGREDIENTS_VW" ("Food_name", "Weight", "Protein", "Carbohydrates", "Fat", "Calories", "Food_id", "Dish_id") AS 
  SELECT c001 as "Food_name"
      ,c002 as "Weight"
      ,c003 as "Protein"
      ,c004 as "Carbohydrates"
      ,c005 as "Fat"
      ,c006 as "Calories"
      ,c007 as "Food_id"
      ,c008 as "Dish_id"
  FROM APEX_collections
 WHERE collection_name = 'INGREDIENTS_COLL'
/
```

I know it is working fine as a source for a report. Problem is when I try to compile a package with procedure that has a insert statement based on a select from this view:

```
Compilation failed,line 95 (10:07:41)
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "DISH_ID": invalid identifierCompilation failed,line 87 (10:07:41)
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

This is the package and procedure:

```
create or replace package body "INGREDIENTS_PKG" is

...

PROCEDURE submit_ingredients(p_dish_id IN NUMBER) IS

BEGIN
  INSERT INTO food_dishes
    SELECT dish_id
          ,food_id
          ,weight
      FROM ((SELECT dish_id
                   ,food_id
                   ,weight
               FROM **ingredients_vw**
              WHERE dish_id = p_dish_id) MINUS
            (SELECT dish_id
                   ,food_id
                   ,weight
               FROM food_dishes
              WHERE dish_id = p_dish_id));
END submit_ingredients;

end "INGREDIENTS_PKG";
```

Could you tell me how to deal with this kind of problem? Is it possible to enforce compilation with this view so that during runtime it will be ok? Or maybe it is no way to compile this package ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"DISH_ID" is an invalid identifier. Your view is using quoted mixed-case identifiers, so the column name in the data dictionary is "Dish_id". When you have quoted identifiers you have to quote all references to them:

```
  INSERT INTO food_dishes
    SELECT "Dish_id"
          ,"Food_id"
          ,"Weight"
      FROM ((SELECT "Dish_id"
                   ,"Food_id"
                   ,"Weight"
               FROM ingredients_vw
              WHERE "Dish_id" = p_dish_id) MINUS
            (SELECT "Dish_id"
                   ,"Food_id"
                   ,"Weight"
               FROM food_dishes
              WHERE "Dish_id" = p_dish_id));
```

I'm assuming you also used quoted identifiers in `food_dishes`, but if not then remove the double-quotes from the `minus` part. [Read more about quoted and non-quoted identifiers.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements008.htm).

You should really specify the column names in the insert too, for clarity and to avoid potential errors (again assuming the identifiers are quoted in the table too):

```
  INSERT INTO food_dishes (
           "Dish_id"
          ,"Food_id"
          ,"Weight")
    SELECT "Dish_id"
          ,"Food_id"
          ,"Weight"
  ...
```

Comment: it's always painful dealing with tables/views that have been defined with mixed case. Avoid if possible.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that your explicitly defined alias from the forced view does not match with how it was called:

```
 c008 as "Dish_id"
```

See the SQL query call:
     PL/SQL: ORA-00904: **"DISH_ID"**: invalid identifier

Note,

```
 "Dish_id" != "DISH_ID"
```

The quotes calls attention to how your names are read.  No quotes makes it non specific.

So caps it all or mg init ca. Dish is served. {The client is satisfied?}